# jquery Json Object Array with Integer value as a Key

Tags: jquery

I want to get format like

```
[{"1":"6"},{"1":"7"},{"2":"8"}] )
```

But this code shows like this:

```
[{"cateid":"6"},{"cateid":"7"},{"cateid":"8"}] )
```

How can I replace `cateid` with integer value?

```
var seleusrv = [];

$('.catechk:checked').each(function(){
    var cateid = $(this).val();
    var i = 0;

    $('.srvchk:checked').each(function(){
        var srvcateid = $(this).data('cateid');
        var srvid = $(this).val();
        if (cateid == srvcateid) {
            seleusrv.push({cateid: srvid});
        }
    });

    if ($(this).closest('ul').find('.srvchk:checked').length == 0) {
        seleusrv.push({cateid: ''});
    }
});
seleusrv = JSON.stringify(seleusrv);
```

This is my Html structure:-

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input class="catechk collapse_allcheckbox" value="1" type="checkbox"> &nbsp; Air Conditioner
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="6" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox"> &nbsp; AC Repair
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="7" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox"> &nbsp; AC Gas Filling
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: This is my Architecture]

Comment: you have to show us a glimpse of your ul-li HTML. Add it in your question

Comment: i have edited and added ul-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your logic like below:-

***Check the below working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var seleusrv = [];
  $('.catechk').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var cateid = $(this).val();
    if (obj.closest('ul').find('.srvchk:checked').length == 0) {
        var temp = {};
        temp[cateid] = '';
        seleusrv.push(temp);
    }else{
      obj.closest('ul').find('.srvchk:checked').each(function(){
        var temp = {};
        var catvalue = $(this).val();
        temp[cateid] = catvalue;
        seleusrv.push(temp);
      });
    }
  });
  seleusrv = JSON.stringify(seleusrv);
  console.log(seleusrv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input class="catechk collapse_allcheckbox" value="1" type="checkbox" checked> &nbsp; Air Conditioner
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="6" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox" checked> &nbsp; AC Repair
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="7" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox" checked> &nbsp; AC Gas Filling
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input class="catechk collapse_allcheckbox" value="2" type="checkbox" checked> &nbsp; Air Conditioner2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="8" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox"> &nbsp; AC Repair2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="srvchk collapse_checkbox" value="9" data-cateid="1" type="checkbox"> &nbsp; AC Gas Filling2
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tries but its give me same variable value as key instead of integer
[{"srvcateid":"6"},{"srvcateid":"7"}]

Comment: Thanks its works but i need one more confirmation, if Subcategory not present, then it will not get into the loop, so it works ?

Comment: @vikasgupta i have modified my code to satisfy both of your requirement.Please check

Comment: @vikasgupta  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use ES6 in your program, the following should work fine:

```
seleusrv.push({[cateid]: ''});
```

See, [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) for more details on the specifications. Otherwise, you will have to create a temporary object and then push it:

```
var temp = {};
temp[cateid] = '';
seleusrv.push(temp);
```

Comment: @vikasgupta -- when you say it doesn't work, you should specify how it doesn't work. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I have tried with your second solution
its gives me repeated values
[{"1":"7"},{"1":"7"}], but i need [{"1":"7"},{"1":"8"}]

Comment: @vikasgupta -- that is out of scope of this question. You should check for the existence of the value, and push only if it doesn't exist.